# How to make a game object consistently jump forward with a constant distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

```
myRB.AddForce(new Vector2(jumpRight,jumpHeight));
```

By using the above code, in Unity2D using c#, the jumping distance varies and goes weird.
How to hop forward keeping the distance constant everytime?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that the trajectory is always the same, then you need to overwrite any velocity it already has.  That can be done just by setting the `velocity` of the `RigidBody2D` equal to the same vector each time.

```
myRB.velocity = new Vector2(jumpRight, jumpHeight);
```